# React Bootstrap Validation use validated input in sub component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using [react-bootstrap-validation](https://github.com/heilhead/react-bootstrap-validation) that decorates the react-bootstrap Input tag.

The ValidatedInput requires that it is inside a Form component. 
When I add my ValidatedInput to a custom sub component I get an error saying it needs to be inside a Form which it is, but I guess it is further down the tree now so can not see the Form.

Is there a way of referencing the parent Form so the ValidatedInput can see the parent.

Looking at the source of the Validation lib I can see that the ValidationInput needs to register to the Form but am not sure how to do this from the sub component.

```js
// Parent render 
render(){
   <Form
   className="fl-form fl-form-inline fl-form-large"
   name="customer-details"
   onValidSubmit={this._handleValidSubmit}
   onInvalidSubmit={this._handleInvalidSubmit}
   validationEvent='onChange'>
    
     <TitleSelect handleChange={this.updateDropDown} value={this.state.form.title} />
     
   </form>
}


// Sub class containing the ValidatedInput
export class TitleSelect extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
      handleChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      value: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }

    render(){

        return (
          <ValidatedInput
            name="title"
            label='title'
            type='select'
            value={this.props.value}
            onChange={this.props.handleChange}
            groupClassName='form-group input-title'
            wrapperClassName='fl-input-wrapper'
            validate='required'
            errorHelp={{
              required: 'Please select a title.'
            }}>

            <option value="" ></option>
            <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
            <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
            <option value="Master">Mstr.</option>
            <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
            <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
            <option value="Reverend">Rev.</option>
            <option value="Doctor">Dr.</option>
            <option value="Professor">Prof.</option>
            <option value="Lord">Lord</option>
            <option value="Lady">Lady</option>
            <option value="Sir">Sir</option>
            <option value="Master">Mstr.</option>
            <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
          </ValidatedInput>
        )
    }
};
```

Comment: Look at inspector to get a clue as to how react is parsing your components. That should give you a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sa @Ваня Решетников said above it's impossible to do it now because of limitations of current design. A solution I went for is this.

1. Convert subcomponent to plain JS object

   ```
   TitleSelect = {
     // move prop types to parent
     renderTitleSelect(){
       ...
     }
   }
   ```
2. Add new object as a mixin to parent and render a function

   ```
   mixins: [TitleSelect],
   ...
   render() {
     <Form ...>
       // parentheses are important!
       {this.renderTitleSelect()}
     </Form>
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I did hear that mixins will be removed at some point so dont want to go down that route. Think I will just move my inputs out of sub components until we can get context introduced.

Comment: I can't see a mention of mixins being removed anywhere (that would be strange to be honest because such mechanism is necessary) and switch to  contexts may take a loooong time

Comment: Read this article about it https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750 the author did also mention it in his talk at react Europe. Think I might not use sub components until we can get context sorted.

Comment: Any progress on this?  I read the linked articles, and found it hard to understand how I would use what is describe there to solve this problem.

Comment: I did end up using something like the mixin shown in the answer

Answer (score 3):

At the moment this is impossible to do. It will be possible in a future release once we get proper parent-based contexts in react and I will migrate the component to contexts. But for now I would recommend to split your `render()` method to couple of smaller ones and reuse them.

Comment: Any progress on "migrating components to contexts"?   In the mean time, could you illustrate your recommendation with a code example?  I can't really fathom how to solve the problem by "splitting `render()`"

Comment: Currently there's no ETA on that feature, sorry. As to splitting `render()` method, consider following example: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/InputBase.js#L184-L207